# What is the purpose of `b` here?

Tags: rust

In this code :

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::Hasher;

let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();

hasher.write_u32(1989);
hasher.write_u8(11);
hasher.write_u8(9);
hasher.write(b"Huh?");

println!("Hash is {:x}!", hasher.finish());
}
```

I understand write_u8, u32, i32 but what's the point of b and why not some other letter, newbie programmer, any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a [Byte string literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-string-literals)

Comment: One quick method for finding out what's going on with types (if your IDE/Editor don't tell you) is to deliberately produce a compiler error message. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a720049802c39ff703535e5566766121)

Answer (score 13):

Any string prefixed by a `b` tells the compiler that the string should be treated as a byte sequence. This is called a byte string literal.

You can read more about it in the [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-string-literals).  In short, a string in Rust is a valid sequence of unicode characters and hence it can be represented as `&[u8]` (A slice containing unsigned 8-bit integers). A byte is also a 8 bit-integer so it is considered as a sequence of unicode bytes.

The `hasher.write(...)` function takes a `&[u8]`, basically a sequence of bytes as parameter. In order to convert your `&str` to bytes, you prefix it with a `b`

Answer (score 3):

`"some string"`:

- is a `&str` which can be converted easily to `&[u8]` as UTF-8
- must result in a sequence of bytes which is valid UTF-8
- can contain any ASCII or Unicode character
- can use ASCII escape sequences (`\x00` to `\x7F`) and Unicode escape sequences (`\u0` to `\u10FFFF`)

`b"some string"`:

- is a `&[u8]` which must be validated as UTF-8 to safely convert to `&str`
- may result in any arbitrary sequence of bytes
- can contain only ASCII characters
- can use full byte escape sequences (`\x00` to `\xFF`)

For example, `b"\xFF"` is valid while `"\xFF"` is not, because the byte FF in hex (255 in decimal) is not allowed anywhere in UTF-8. Similarly, `""` is valid while `b""` is not, because emoji are part of Unicode and not ASCII.

As an interesting side note, `"\uFF"` (which is the same as `"ÿ"`) does not convert to `b"\xFF"` but rather to `b"\xC3\xBF"` because UTF-8 uses multiple bytes to encode characters outside of ASCII.

Comment: To elaborate on the last sentence: when the compiler sees the string literal "\uFF" in the source, it will compile this to 2 bytes: 0xC3 and 0xBF, which is the UTF-8 representation of the unicode value 0xFF. If you don't understand why this happens, read up on the history of UTF-8 encoding.
In any case, this answer is by far the best explanation of byte string literals! Better than the Rust reference.